# add data labels to google chart with no set columns

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a chart that allows the user to select an option to compare to a statewide average. The chart works fine until I use the stringify method to create annotations - the number of columns varies based on the selection. What is your advice on how to retain this functionality, and still have data labels?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table', 'corechart']});
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
function initialize() {drawVisualizations();
function drawVisualizations() {drawChart(); drawTable();} //drawC();} 

//main chart
function drawChart() {
var dataCap = document.getElementById("selected2").value;
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m3ujxzPQJh3haReNDzGGF73Mh6-u6HxyCVPK_5MK2hw/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&range=A1:A5,E1:E5,' + dataCap); query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  var data = response.getDataTable();
   var options = {
    'title':'College Readiness',
    'subTitle':'Test',
    'titleTextStyle': {fontSize: '24', color: 'teal', fontName: '"Arial"', isHTML: true},
    hAxis: {'title': 'Percent of Students Ready', 'textStyle': {color: 'gray', fontSize: '9'}, 'minValue': '0', 'maxValue':'1','format': 'percent'},
    vAxis: {'title': 'Academic Year', 'textStyle': {bold: true, fontSize: '16'}, 'minValue': '0', 'maxValue':'1'},
    legend: {'position': 'top', 'maxLines': 5, 'textStyle': {bold: true, fontSize: '16', fontName: "'Arial'"}},
    tooltip: {
    textStyle: {fontName: "'Arial'"}},
        series: {
        0: {pointsVisible: true, color: '#003366'},
        1: {pointsVisible: true, color: '#cc0000'}
    },
  annotations: {
  textStyle: {bold: true,color: '#000000', fontName: "'Arial'"},
  stem:{color: 'none'}
  }};


function handleQueryResponse(response) {var data = response.getDataTable()};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));chart.draw(data, options);}

//current stats sidebar
function drawTable() {
var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m3ujxzPQJh3haReNDzGGF73Mh6-u6HxyCVPK_5MK2hw/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&range=A:E');
  query2.send(handleQueryResponse2);
}

function handleQueryResponse2(response) {
var data2 = response.getDataTable();
var options2 = {'sort': 'disable'};
var chart2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('data_div'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);}
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {text-align: center;}
#chart_div {width: 900px; margin: 20px auto; height: 600px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<label for="selected2">You are viewing:</label>
<select id="selected2" onChange="initialize()">
      <option selected value="">Statewide average only</option>
      <option value="B1:B5">Fake University 1 compared to statewide average</option>
      <option value="C1:C5">Fake University 2 compared to statewide average</option>
      <option value="D1:D5">Fake University 3 compared to statewide average</option>
  </select>
<input onClick="window.open('datatest21-data.html')" type="button" value="Download the complete data set" />
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="data_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the stringify method I was using, but it messes up the above code:

```
//
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, { calc: "stringify",
sourceColumn: 1,
type: "string",
role: "annotation"},
2,{ calc: "stringify",
sourceColumn: 2,
type: "string",
role: "annotation" }]);
//
```

It could be that I'm doing this all wrong - advice, appreciated. This type of coding is new to me.

Comment: do you know which columns need an annotation? you could build `view.setColumns` dynamically based on `data.getNumberOfColumns()`...

Comment: I've got it working using the method you mentioned, but have lost interactivity. See post below.

Comment: It's something wrong with the initialize code. If I take the drawChart function out, it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now with set columns, but the dropdown to change the value no longer works. My guess is that once the graph shifts into DataView (rather than DataTable), it becomes "read-only" and the interactivity is lost. (This example is using another chart.) I need a way of redrawing the table when another option is selected.
[code]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table', 'corechart']});
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
function initialize() {drawVisualizations(); function drawVisualizations() {drawChart(); drawTable();} //drawC();} 

//main chart
function drawChart() {
var dataCap = document.getElementById("selected2").value;
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m3ujxzPQJh3haReNDzGGF73Mh6-u6HxyCVPK_5MK2hw/gviz/tq?sheet=Enrollment&range=' + dataCap); query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
var data = response.getDataTable();
  //
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,
                       {calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 4,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation"}
                       ]);
                     //
   var options = {
   height: 500,
   chartArea: {'left': '5%'},
   isStacked: true,
   hAxis: {'textStyle': {'fontSize':11}},
   vAxis: {'textStyle': {'fontSize':11}, 'maxValue':110000},
    legend: {'position': 'top', 'maxLines': 5, 'textStyle': {bold: true, fontSize: 11, fontName: '"Arial"'}},
    tooltip: {
    textStyle: {fontName: "'Arial'"}},
        series: {
        0: {color: 'navy'},
        1: {color: 'teal'}
    },
  annotations: {
  textStyle: {bold: true,color: '#000000', fontName: "'Arial'"},
  alwaysOutside: true,
  isHTML: true,
  stemColor: 'none',
  text: 'test'
  }};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));chart.draw(view, options);}


//current stats sidebar
function drawTable() {
var dataCap2 = document.getElementById("selected3").value;
var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m3ujxzPQJh3haReNDzGGF73Mh6-u6HxyCVPK_5MK2hw/gviz/tq?' + dataCap2);
  query2.send(handleQueryResponse2);
}

function handleQueryResponse2(response) {
var data2 = response.getDataTable();
var options2 = {
    height: 300,
    chartArea: {'left': '5%'},
    hAxis: {'textStyle': {'fontSize':11}},
    vAxis: {'minValue': '0', 'maxValue':'1', 'format':'percent', 'textStyle': {'fontSize':11}},
    legend: {'position': 'top', 'maxLines': 5, 'textStyle': {bold: true, fontSize: 11, fontName: '"Arial"'}},
    tooltip: {
    textStyle: {fontName: "'Arial'"}},
        series: {
        //0: {pointsVisible: true, color: '#003366', pointSize: 6},
        0: {pointsVisible: true, color: '#cc0000', pointSize: 6}
    },
  annotations: {
  textStyle: {bold: true,color: '#000000', fontName: "'Arial'"},
  stem:{color: 'none'}
  } 
    };
var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('data_div'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);}
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#wrapper {width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
#current {float: right; width: 28%; background-color: #ececec; padding: 0 1em; font-size: 80%; margin-left: 5%;}
h2 {margin-top: 2em;}
dt {font-weight: bold; margin-top: .5em;}
dd {padding-top: .25em; margin-top: .25em;}
dd.total {border-top: 1px solid #000;}
#chart_div, #data_div {width: 75%;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">


<h1>Student Enrollment in State Universities and Community Colleges</h1>


<h3>Trend Data</h3>
<form>
<label for="selected2">You are viewing:</label>
<select id="selected2" onchange="initialize()">
      <option selected value="A1:E8">All state universities</option>
      <option value="F1:I8">Fake University 1</option>
</select>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<input onClick="window.open('')" type="button" value="Download the complete data set" />
</form>

<h2>Community and Technical Colleges</h2>

<h3>Trend Data</h3>
<form>
<label for="selected3">You are viewing:</label>
<select id="selected3" onChange="initialize()">
<option selected value="sheet=GraduationRates-3Yr&range=A1:B11">3-Year graduation rate</option>
<option value="sheet=GraduationRates-2Yr&range=A1:B11">2-Year graduation rate</option>
</select>
<div id="data_div"></div>
<input onClick="window.open('')" type="button" value="Download the complete data set" />
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[/code]